# Android Studio Ошибка:"Unable to connect to adb.Check the Event log for possible issues verify that your localhost entry is pointing to 127.0.0.1"

Tags: android, android-studio

После сегодняшнего обновления Android Studio при запуске эмулятора получаю ошибку:

> Unable to connect to adb.Check the Event log for possible issues
>   verify that your localhost entry is pointing to 127.0.0.1

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке подключиться к "железному" планшету то же самое.

Пробовал решить проблему как предлагают [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55762216/not-able-to-connect-adb-after-upgrate-android-studio-to-3-4) и [здесь](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/203258/android-studio-unable-to-see-any-connected-targets-neither-hardware-nor-virtual). Не помогло.

Как быть?

Answer (score 2):

Что я только не пробовал делать, но в итоге решил вопрос самостоятельно. Ответ пишу на случай, если кто-то то же столкнётся с подобным.

Проблема оказалась в том, что эмулятор Genymotion был запущен раньше, чем студия.

Поэтому если пользуетесь Genymotion лучше всегда запускать сначала студию, а потом его.

Answer (score 1):

Я столкнулся с такой же ситуацией когда просто поставил сегодня на чистую систему сначала Android Studio а потом и эмулятор Genymotion. Пробовал я вариант решения из вашего ответа, но он мне не помог :( Дальше я попробовал те ссылки которые вы приложили к вопросу, и там тоже мне ничего не помогло. И тогда я решил что проблема где-то в настройках эмулятора, и оказалось что решение именно там. Есть раздел под названием ADB  и там можно выбрать размещение SDK. На выбор два варианта - стандартный от Genymotion или выбрать папку где хранится SDK которое юзает студия. Я установил тот который с выбором папки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и эмулятор появился в списке устройств. Может это конечно частный случай, но может кому поможет :)