# Не запускаются проекты в android studio

Tags: android, adb

Недавно столкнулся с такой ошибкой:

> Unable to detect adb version, adb output

Затем, когда я нажимаю кнопку "Run", выдаёт ошибку :

> Unable to conneсt to ADB. Chek the Event Log for possible issues. Verify that your localhost entry is pointing to 127.0.0.1 or:: 1 for IPv4 or IPv6, respectively

Я с этой ошибкой сталкиваюсь впервые, раньше такого никогда не было и всё хорошо загружалось. Объясните пожалуйста, в чём причина этого, почему перестал запускаться adb драйвер? И как мне это исправить?

Я пытался запустить adb вручную c помощью команды adb start-server, но мне писало "команда adb не является внутренней или внешней командой" Пробовал команду:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`adb kill-server` не помогает. Windows и Android Studio переустанавливал , так-же не помогает. Реального устройства нет поэтому пользуюсь Genymotion.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/979738/android-studio-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0unable-to-connect-to-adb-check-the-event-log-for-possible [вот человек вроде с этим же сталкивался]

Comment: Он там написал что нужно запустить вначале AS, а затем genimoution. Я так попробовал ничего не вышло. я кажется догадался в чём там проблема. когда разберусь отпишу.